# Equality between a set and the limit superior of a sequence of sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

I have been asked to discuss whether
$\{x : \varlimsup f_n(x) \gt a\}$
is equal to $\varlimsup \{x : f_n(x) \gt a \}$

I know there are many missing details but this is the way my professor has given the class the exercise. I assume $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N} , f_n : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.
The professor told us that the sets are not equal because we have $\{x : \varlimsup f_n(x) > a\} \subset 
\varlimsup \{x : f_n(x) > a \}$

but

$\{x : \varlimsup f_n(x) > a\}  \not\supset 
\varlimsup \{x : f_n(x) > a \}$

I think I understand why the first statement is true.

But the professor told us that the second is true because
$y\in\varlimsup \{x : f_n(x) > a \}$ only implies $y\in\{x : \varlimsup f_n(x) \ge a\}$
which I don't understand. Could someone explain it to me ?

Similarly, we have been told that $\{x : \varlimsup f_n(x) \ge a\}$
is not equal to $\varlimsup \{x : f_n(x) \ge a \}$

Is it for the same reasons ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y \in \varlimsup \{x : f_n(x) > a \}$ means that $\displaystyle y \in \bigcup_{j \ge n} \{x : f_j(x) > a \}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, i.e. that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, there exists $j \ge n$ such that $f_j(y) \gt a$.

While $y \in \{x : \varlimsup f_n(x) > a \}$ means that $\varlimsup f_n(y) > a$. So let $b = \varlimsup f_n(y) > a$. For all $n \in \mathbb N$, it exists $j \ge n$ such that $f_j(y) \ge \frac{a+b}{2}$.

*Do you see the difference?*

To get an example, suppose that $f_n(x) = a + \frac{1}{n}$. We have $\varlimsup \{x : f_n(x) > a \} = \mathbb R$ while $\{x : \varlimsup f_n(x) > a \} = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think my problem is I am having difficulties understanding what $\varlimsup f_n(x)$ means. Is it $\varlimsup f_n(x) = \inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \sup_{k \ge n} (f_k(x))$ ? That is what I thought I understood but I am having difficulties understanding with that definition.

Comment: Your definition of $\limsup$ is correct. I suggest that you try to apply it to the $f_n$ example I provided.

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much !